# Is there a command in R to delete all rows from a dataframe which contain NAs only?

Tags: r, dplyr, psych

I have a dataframe, namely 'Beta_corr_only_Significant', in R which contains several rows (>700), all of which that contain some NAs. What I would like to do is to generate a second dataframe, copy of the first one, but without all the rows in which ALL the values are NAs.

I have tried using this command with the help of the {dplyr} package:

```
Beta_corr_noNAs <- Beta_corr_only_Significant %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ !is.na(.)))
```

But keep receiving this error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

And I am not sure why that is the case. The object I am trying to manipulate is a dataframe generated using the corr.test command, from the {psych} package in R.

Comment: `df[rowSums(!is.na(x)) > 0,] `

Comment: This solved the issue, thank you!